# How to find if there are empty attributes in XML?

Tags: python, xml

Having a XML like this one (located in /home/user/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DataClient xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cnmc="http://www.example.com/Tipos_DataClient" xmlns="http://www.example.com/DataClient">
   <PersonalData Operation="3" Date="2022-09-06">
      <ExtendedData>
         <Person Code="XXX" OtherCode="Y12354"/>
      </ExtendedData>
      <Home Type="Street" Num="10" Code="12003" Poblation="Imaginary street"/>
   </PersonalData>
</DataClient>
```

How could I identify if the "Num" attribute is empty? And then generate a list of all those elements that have the "Num" empty...

I tried to count all those with "None" as value, but it always returns 0:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('/home/user/file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
b = None
a = sum(1 for s in root.findall('./DataClient/PersonalData/ExtendedData/Num') if s.b)

print (a)
```

Comment: Just to be clear on naming conventions, `Num` is an attribute. `<Home>` or `<Person>`, etc, are tags.

Comment: Your "findall" searches for tags named "Num" but there aren't any.

Comment: You're searching inside the `ExtendedData` element, but making some inferences about your data it looks like no element inside `ExtendedData` is going to have a `Num` attribute (that appears to be part of the `Home` element, which is outside of the `ExtendedData` element).

Answer (score 0):

Since Python's `etree` API maps attributes to dictionaries, consider [**`dict.get`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to check for specific attribute. Also, you need to use `namespaces` argument of [**`findall`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) since XML contains a default namespace.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

tree = ET.parse('/home/user/file.xml')

nmsp = {"doc": "http://www.example.com/DataClient"}
xpath = "./doc:DataClient/doc:PersonalData/doc:Home"

a = sum(1 for node in tree.findall(xpath, nmsp) if node.attrib.get("Num") is None)
```